# Prolem with converting point from table cell

Tags: ios, uitableview, autolayout

I have following hierarchy: Controller.view [tableView, overlayView]. Table view has top inset of 16 points from parent view via constraint, overlay view - not.

Inside table cell content view I have another view `responder` and I want to show it's image on view `overlayView`.

If I use this code (inside overlay view):

```
CGRect frame;
CGPoint origin = [responder convertPoint:responder.frame.origin toView:self];
// FIXME origin.y -= 16;
frame.origin = origin;
frame.size = responder.frame.size;
_imageView.frame = frame;

UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(responder.bounds.size, NO, 0);
[responder drawViewHierarchyInRect:responder.bounds afterScreenUpdates:YES];
_imageView.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

I get `imageView` with 16 points offset from `responder` origin and image not fit into original view. So I have to use line with FIXME mark to have origin points equal. Why converting don't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be converting the point from the `responder`'s `superview`, not the `responder` itself. Change your second line to this:

```
CGPoint origin = [responder.superview convertPoint:responder.frame.origin toView:self];
```